# voice = await channel.connect() not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.net

My discord bot is not joining voice channels here is the code

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    if(ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.voice_client
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('test.wav')
        player = voice.play(source)
   else:
        await ctx.send("Error: You are not in a voice channel.")
```

the error:

```
ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\-----\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Cosmic\main.py", line 37, in join
    voice = await channel.connect()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError:         'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

I did pip install Pynacl and imported it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import nacl
```

Comment: Obviously, `voice_client` must not be `None` for you to be able to call _anything_ on it. Check that before you try to use it.

Comment: ...taking a quick look at the docs, it appears to me that you should be calling `connect` _on a `VoiceChannel`_ to create a `VoiceClient`. If you haven't done this, and so haven't created a VoiceClient yet, then having `None` in the `voice_client` property makes some intuitive sense. (Comment, not an answer, since I'm not speaking from authority or experience and haven't tested this).

Comment: How do I add something to voice_client?